# Reduce space(s) between columns in row bootstrap grid layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to css, bootstrap. I have divided my screen into two divs. On the right side, using a bootstrap container div. And displaying my form fields as below. Each row contains 8 columns.

[image]

I tried to use no-gutters on my row div. But it removes entire space between columns which makes less readable and poor format. I would required to reduce the space to half in order to fit the last blank line after TWG fully fit inside my form container. Would like to reduce the space to half between Label and blank line.

```
col-eq{width: calc(100% / 8);max-width:50%} 
.myContainer { background-color: lightyellow; border: 1px solid #aaa;}
<div> </div>
```

How to make my container to adjust displaying form with input columns inside box? or how to reduce the whitespaces to half between label and blank line?

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap?

Comment: The Bootstrap docs are simple and comprehensive. I suggest that you become familiar with your version top to bottom. [Bootstrap 5 gutters](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/gutters/) | [Bootstrap 4 gutters](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#gutters)

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap 5.x you can just add class `gx-1` or `gx-2` to your **.row**. Using Bootstrap 4.x this is a lot more difficult with negative margins on rows and extra padding on columns

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <form>
      <div class="row gx-2">
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Field 1">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Field 2">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Field 3">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Field 4">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Field 5">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Field 6">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Field 7">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Field 8">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</section
```